# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click' while trying to loop through the hrefs and click them through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[This is the tag containing `href`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3vSV.png).
[This is the HTML of one of the links when I inspected it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRwXB.png).

The code I used to for looping through the links is:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem)
    elem.get_attribute("href").click()
```

but I am getting the error:

> File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/sel.py", line 31, in
>
> (session="7896348772e450d1658543632013ca4e",
>   element="0.06572622905717385-1")>
>
> ```
> elem.get_attribute("href").click()
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Can any one help please.

Comment: could you share relevant html ?

Comment: @prany do you want the whole source code?

Comment: @vijayMV - not whole source code but the one relevant to your question

Comment: @prany i have attached the image of one of the links html in the post.

Comment: I can't see any href in your html

Comment: @vijayMV, so, where is `a` tag in provided HTML by you?

Comment: @prany sorry i have attached another image showing href and a tag

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'
```

...implies that you script/program have attempted to invoke `click()` on a `string` object.

### What went wrong

As per the line of code:

```
elem.get_attribute("href").click()
```

You have extracted the **href** attribute of the first element from the *List* **elems**. `get_attribute()` method returns a **string**. *String* data types can't invoke `click()` method. Hence you see the error.

### Solution

Now, in all possibilities as you are extracting the `href` attributes and you want to open the *Links* and a viable solution will be to open the (href) links in the adjacent `TABs` as follows:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem)
    my_href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
    # perform your tasks in the new window and switch back to the parent windown for the remaining hrefs
```

Comment: +1 for the new window trick.  OP might want to checkout the `window_handles` and, `switch_to` from the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `get_attribute()` method returns the value of the attribute. In this case, the attribute is `href`so, it returned `str` obj. Note that, the web element `elem` is clickable. But, if you click on the `elem`. It will take you to the next page hence, iterating over all these web elements (`elems`) won't be possible as, driver will move on to next page!

Alternate way, to achieve what you are looking for is to create a list of links and, iterate over it like below:

```
links = []   
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem)
    links.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # do you stuff
```

This way, we are making sure to collect all the links from the web element list i.e. `elems` by iterating over it. After collecting all the links and storing them in the list, we iterate over the collected list of urls.

Comment: Good job pointing out the problem with the loop. If the user has to perform different actions on each link, he would have to add few more conditions.

Comment: @Shivam Mishra if i want to extract some information from each link what should i add more to the existing code?

Comment: Thanks Shivam Mishra. 
@vijayMV check [DebanjanB's Answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057744/3083094)

Comment: @vijayMV What exactly do you want to test in each link? You could use any method in the answers. What I wanted to say was, if you use the method in this answer, you would have to check which page the driver is currently into i.e. if link==link1, perform test1 and so on. That's because I assume you have to perform different operations on different links.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_attribute("href")` returns the STRING of the url whichever the element is pointing to. If you want to click on the hyperlink element, just do:

```
for elem in elems:
    print(elem)
    elem.click()
    driver.back() //to go back the previous page and continue over the links
```

On a sidenote, if you want to print the URL of the hyperlink which you are clicking, you can use your `get_attribute()` method:

```
print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```