# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys' error using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, attributeerror

This is the code from my Twitter Bot Project.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username, password, search_text):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/home?lang=en")
        time.sleep(2)
        # Enter your username
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')\
            .send_keys(username)
        # Enter your password
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/label/div/div[2]/div/input') \
            .send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[3]/div/div')\
            .click()
        time.sleep(3)
        # Enter text in the search box
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input')\
            .send_keys(search_text)
        search_text.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(4)
        while True:
            pass


TwitterBot("rmail@gmail.com", "abcd1234", "lamborghini")
```

When I try to run this script, I am getting an AttributeError.

```
File "C:\Users\Praneeth Ravuri\PycharmProjects\Twitter Bots\Open Twitter Bots .py", line 24, in __init__
    search_text.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Can someone solve my problem and edit this code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on the line the error gets thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use twitter so I don't exactly know what search box you are talking about, but If you just want to enter some text in the search box and hit Enter, Then, replace this:

```
# Enter text in the search box
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(search_text)
search_text.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

with this:

```
# Enter text in the search box
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input')
element.send_keys(search_text)
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I can't test this on my machine as I don't use twitter but I think it should work. Please let me know if this helps. Thanks

Comment: Sorry it is not working. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to modify the code. I've updated the answer. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

The `.send_keys(...)` method belongs to the **`WebElement`**, not the string.

It's what causes your code to produce this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Instead of this line:

```
# Enter text in the search box
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input')\
    .send_keys(search_text)
search_text.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You can change with this code:

```
search_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input')
search_box.send_keys(search_text)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You should initialize `search_box` as **`WebElement`**, put the text then submit with enter keys.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

...implies that you script/program have attempted to invoke `send_keys()` on a `string` object.

---

### What went wrong

As per the line of code:

```
search_text.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You are trying to invoke `send_keys()` on the variable `search_text` which is of type **string** passed to `def __init__(self,username, password, search_text)` method. Where as `send_keys()` is a method associated with [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

You need to invoke `send_keys()` on the *WebElement* as follows:

```
self.element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input')
self.element.send_keys(search_text)
self.element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

---

### Refrences

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click' while trying to loop through the hrefs and click them through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056256/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-click-while-trying-to-loop-throu/51057744#51057744)